# Prevent flickering when drawing many images on mouse move

Tags: .net, winforms, image

I'm looking for a fast way to draw images that can draw 256 32x32 **PRELOADED** images everytime OnMouseMove is called onto the screen without flickering crazily like using System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage. Thanks :)

Comment: Use *double buffering*.

Comment: Post your best attempt.

Comment: Pick C# *or* VB.NET (whatever you've written/are writing code in), but *not* both unless they are both actually relevant.

Comment: Please show the code for how you are currently drawing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

Here's the absolute BEST way to do double buffering with the GDI+:

Add the following 3 lines into your form's constructor (the New method, where it says "put initialization code here"):

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, True)
SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, True)
SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, True)
```

Now, draw all of your graphics in the Paint event. They will appear only after the Paint event terminates!